# how to perform validation for multiple fields in JSR223 assertion in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I have written below script in JSR223 assertion to validate a field. Now I want to perform validation for multiple fields like first name, email but I don't want to write separate script for each. How this can be achieved in the same JSR223 assertion script?

def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name

if (lastName != 'Lawson') {
AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect value" + lastName)
}

Below is the Json:
 { "per_page": 6, "total": 12, "data": [ { "last_name": "Lawson", "id": 7, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg", "first_name": "Michael", "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Ferguson", "id": 8, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg", "first_name": "Lindsay", "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Funke", "id": 9, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg", "first_name": "Tobias", "email": "tobias.funke@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Fields", "id": 10, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg", "first_name": "Byron", "email": "byron.fields@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Edwards", "id": 11, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg", "first_name": "George", "email": "george.edwards@reqres.in" }, { "last_name": "Howell", "id": 12, "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg", "first_name": "Rachel", "email": "rachel.howell@reqres.in" } ], "page": 2, "total_pages": 2, "support": { "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!", "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading" } }

I tried with below script as well, but it is giving me result for last name only not for both email and last name:

def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()) 
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name 
def email = responseJson.data[0].email
if (email != 'test') {
AssertionResult.setFailure(true) 
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect email value" + email) 
}
if (lastName != 'test') {
AssertionResult.setFailure(true) 
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect last name value\n" + lastName)
}

else 
{
AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("correct value");
}

Answer (score 0):

If you really "have written" the script it should not be a problem for you to add more checks like this one for the last name:

```
def responseJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def lastName = responseJson.data[0].last_name
def email = responseJson.data[0].email

if (lastName != 'Lawson') {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect value" + lastName)
}
if (email != 'michael.lawson@reqres.in') {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Incorrect value" + lastName)
}
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, I tried with multiple If statement but I am getting result for second condition only, even if both the condition failed. Can you please help?